# Using pointers with structures to pass data to functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

This is a program for a class project. It is suppose to be able to create and edit structures. The CreatRec function works fine. For the ModifyRec I am trying to send it the array by pointers in order to avoid having to "copy" the data. However, I am having trouble getting it to actually change the array. ATM The line at the bottom (gr[change].lastname= *info;) is not working at all. I really have no clue what I am doing wrong here.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    int recordname;
    char lastname[10];
    char firstname[10];
    float math;
    float english;
    float science;
};

//prototypes
int menu();
struct student  CreatRec(int);
void ModifyRec(struct student*);


void main()
{
    int option, j;//option will be for users menu choice, j makes for loop work for creatrec
    struct student grades[10];
    j = 0;
    option=Menu();
    if (option == 1)
        for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
            (grades[j + 0]) = CreatRec(j);
    else if (option==2)
        ModifyRec(grades);//dont need & is smart bc array


    printf("%s",grades[0].lastname);//This line is checking to see if ModifyRec actaully worked

    //free(grades);2
    while (1);
}


int Menu()
{
    int choi;
    printf("Please choose one of the following options.\n 1) Create  New Student Records.\n 2) Modify an Existing Student Record\n");
    printf(" 3) Print a New Sutdent Record.\n 4) Quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choi);
    return choi;
}
struct student  CreatRec(int i)
{
    struct student qr;
    //qr = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student)*6);

    printf("RecordNum %i\n", i);
    printf("Please enter last name-->");
    scanf("%s", &qr.lastname);
    printf("Please enter first name-->");
    scanf("%s", &qr.firstname);
    printf("Please math grade-->");
    scanf("%f", &qr.math);
    printf("Please english grade-->");
    scanf("%f", &qr.english);
    printf("Please science grade-->");
    scanf("%f", &qr.science);
    return qr;
}

void ModifyRec(struct student gr[])
{
    int change;
    char feild[10], info[10];

    printf("Which record would you like to change?\n");
    scanf("%d", &change);
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("Which feild would you like to edit?\n");
    scanf("%s", &feild);
    rewind(stdin);
    printf("Enter info\n");
    scanf("%s", &info);

    if (!strcmp("lastname", feild))
        gr[change].lastname= *info;//NOT WORKING

}
```

Comment: Why the C++ tag? A typo?

Comment: the site wrote that tag for me

Comment: it wasnted allowing be to enter info on the next time when I didnt have the rewind

Answer (score 1):

First of all I do not see a great sense in expression `grades[j + 0]` of statement

```
    for (j = 0; j<10; j++)
        (grades[j + 0]) = CreatRec(j);
```

These statements

```
printf("Please enter last name-->");
scanf("%s", &qr.lastname);
printf("Please enter first name-->");
scanf("%s", &qr.firstname);
```

have to be substituted for

```
printf("Please enter last name-->");
scanf("%s", qr.lastname);
printf("Please enter first name-->");
scanf("%s", qr.firstname);
```

And this statement

```
if (!strcmp("lastname", feild))
    gr[change].lastname= *info;//
```

has to be substituted for

```
if (!strcmp("lastname", feild))
    strcpy( gr[change].lastname, info );
```

Comment: Ok so your second substitutions works wonderful, thank you so much! However, the first one, that doesnt work one it gets down to scanning in the ints.  As for the first bit, I have an array of 10 structures, so I have to fill in all 10 with the creatrec

Comment: @user3486669 You have to enter ENTER key after each data that the input would be correct.

Comment: Im not quite sure I understand what you mean

Comment: @user3486669 When you enterd for example last name press Enter key

Comment: oh yes, I know that, and it works thats way with just the chars, but not the floats

Answer (score 0):

`gr[change].lastname` is a char array, not a pointer. You can't reassign it. In this case, you probably ought to do `scanf("%s", gr[change].lastname);` and skip `char info[10]` altogether.

Comment: ok but later on I how to allow them to edit other fields as well, (firstname) etc. Are you saying I should have scanf("%s", FEILD) for each one?

Comment: you could. another possibility is to set up a `char *destination` to point to a specific field and then `scanf("%s", destination)`.